# How to do I get a media wiki page to look like a word doc with a standard template defined by the Docs dept?

Tags: ms-word, pdf-generation, mediawiki

We have a standard word template used by the Doc dept. When they have finished a doc, they archive it in pdf.  It is immediately obsolete.

My proposed solution is to use media wiki transclusions to compile a doc from reusable 'idea pages'. The analogy is to have reusable text the way we have reusable code. So if a step in a process is to 'Plug in the D* thing'  There would be a wiki page for that. It would be included by reference (transclusion} in any document that need that information, and it is maintained in one place, eliminating a doc search in all the places it might be when it changes.

I have prototyped it this far, and from a git diff between tags, I can produce a list of system tests for that tag by wrapping the lines of the output with transclusion brackets..

Now I am looking to make the document look and feel like the Word standard doc for archival purposes.  I wish to print to pdf and have the standard word styles apply.

I am tempted to:

1. Copy a really ugly word style sheet and trim it of unused stuff.
2. Use templates to impose styles on mediawiki stuff (makes ugly markup)
3. Use a magic style converter.  I am hoping for this.

Any ideas?

Comment: What steps do you currently use to make a doc (is it actually a .docx, or something else) from a wiki page (or whatever you are starting with)? (I'm not familiar with the media wiki side, just the ms-word side).

Comment: It is MSWord  docx. They will print to pdf from there to archive.